# Spring 3, PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter can't return 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

I am trying to write PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter which is testing few RequestHeader fields and according to that either continue the processing or returns the error.

My filter code is:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    int status = doAuthenticate((HttpServletRequest) request, (HttpServletResponse) response);

    if (status != HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(status);
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("TestHeader", Integer.toString(status));            
    }
    else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Using this code I can send any statuses started from 200 or 300 but if I set the status to one of the values 400 - 5XX the response is sent with 200 OK.

My xml filter definition is:

```
    <security:port-mappings>
        <security:port-mapping http="#{webProperties.httpPort}" https="#{webProperties.httpsPort}"/>
    </security:port-mappings>

    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
</security:http>
```

I haven't done much with Spring before, just few simple servlets. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to be using a custom [`AccessDecisionVoter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionVoter.html)?

Comment: I see this name the first time. I will Google it and see if it helps.